JOLT TRANSFORM separating array element
I have the below input:
[
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "OutboundQueueId": "000000610",
    "TransactionType": "WorkCreation",
    "InventLocationId": "XXX",
    "SubscriptionId": "PickingWorkCreate",
    "data01": "1000000528",
    "data02": "4343434343",
    "data03": "53010301",
    "data04": "2",
    "data05": "XXXXXXXX",
    "data06": "PA-VLM",
    "data07": "10",
    "data08": "33333",
    "data09": "33333333",
    "data10": "MERCEDES STAR",
    "Pay1": "00000207",
    "Pay2": "10",
    "Pay3": "XXXXXXX",
    "Pay4": "XXX",
    "Pay5": "DDDDDDDDDD"
  }
]

The current spec is :
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "HEADER_SOURCE": "HOST",
        "HEADER_DESTINATION": "WAMAS",
        "HEADER_SEQUENCE": "0",
        "HEADER_CREATIONTIME": "${CreationTime}",
        "HEADER_RECORDTYPENAME": "WLSPD001",
        "clientId": "DEFAULT",
        "priority": "5",
        "typeId": "SHPG",
        "zone": "ZONE1",
        "sysPartnerLine": "1",
        "variant": "1",
        "clientId1": "DEFAULT",
        "clientId2": "DEFAULT",
        "clientId3": "DEFAULT",
        "clientId4": "DEFAULT",
        "demandNo1": "${demandNo}",
        "demandNo2": "${demandNo}",
        "demandNo3": "${demandNo}",
        "demandNo4": "${demandNo}"
      }
    }
},
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "HEADER_SOURCE": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].header.FULL.HEADER_SOURCE",
        "HEADER_DESTINATION": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].header.FULL.HEADER_DESTINATION",
        "HEADER_SEQUENCE": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].header.FULL.HEADER_SEQUENCE",
        "HEADER_CREATIONTIME": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].header.FULL.HEADER_CREATIONTIME",
        "HEADER_RECORDTYPENAME": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].header.FULL.HEADER_RECORDTYPENAME",
        "clientId": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.clientId",
        "data01": ["DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.demandNo", "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.WLSPDL001[&1].demandNo", "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.WLSPDL001[&1].hostWorkId"],
        "priority": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.priority",
        "zone": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.zone",
        "typeId": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.typeId",
        "TransactionType": {
          "WorkCreation": {
            "#CREATE": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&3].body.WLSPD001.operation"
          },
          "WorkCompletion": {
            "#COMPLETE": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&3].body.WLSPD001.operation"
          },
          "WorkCanceled": {
            "#CANCEL": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&3].body.WLSPD001.operation"
          }
        },
        "sysPartnerLine": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.WLSPDL001[&1].sysPartnerLine",
        "data02": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.WLSPDL001[&1].itemNo",
        "variant": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.WLSPDL001[&1].variant",
        "data04": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.WLSPDL001[&1].baseQty",
        "data03": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.WLSPDL001[&1].hostLuIds",
        "data05": {
          "@": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&2].body.WLSPD001.WLSPDEXTREF001[].clientId"
        },
        "Pay3": {
          "@": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&2].body.WLSPD001.WLSPDEXTREF001[].clientId"
        },
        "demandNo1": {
          "@": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&2].body.WLSPD001.WLSPDEXTREF001[].demandNo1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

The current spec output
{
  "DI_TELEGRAMS" : {
    "DI_TELEGRAM" : [ {
      "header" : {
        "FULL" : {
          "HEADER_SOURCE" : "HOST",
          "HEADER_DESTINATION" : "WAMAS",
          "HEADER_SEQUENCE" : "0",
          "HEADER_CREATIONTIME" : "${CreationTime}",
          "HEADER_RECORDTYPENAME" : "WLSPD001"
        }
      },
      "body" : {
        "WLSPD001" : {
          "clientId" : "DEFAULT",
          "demandNo" : "1000000528",
          "WLSPDL001" : [ {
            "demandNo" : "1000000528",
            "hostWorkId" : "1000000528",
            "sysPartnerLine" : "1",
            "itemNo" : "4343434343",
            "variant" : "1",
            "baseQty" : "2",
            "hostLuIds" : "53010301"
          } ],
          "priority" : "5",
          "zone" : "ZONE1",
          "typeId" : "SHPG",
          "operation" : "CREATE",
           "priority" : "5",
          "zone" : "ZONE1",
          "typeId" : "SHPG",
          "operation" : "CREATE",
          "WLSPDEXTREF001" : [ {
            "clientId" : [ "DEFAULT", "DEFAULT", "DEFAULT", "DEFAULT" ],
            "demandNo" : [ "${demandNo}", "${demandNo}", "${demandNo}", "${demandNo}" ]
          } ]
        }
      }
    } ]
  }
}


But for the last part i need as
"WLSPDEXTREF001" : [
{
"clientId1" : "DEFAULT",
"demandNo1" : "${demandNo}"
}, {
"clientId2" : "XXXXXXX",
"demandNo2" : "${demandNo}"
},
{
"clientId3" : "XXXXXXX",
"demandNo3" : "${demandNo}"
}, .....
]
Need to seperate both array elements to and club as one group and so on. please help me..

Your jolt is almost complete, the one thing it misses is the final aggregation to obtain the output you are searching for.
To let you better understand what I did, I will simplify the input to something smaller:
Let's say your input is this:
[
  {
    "clientId1": "DEFAULT",
    "clientId2": "DEFAULT",
    "clientId3": "DEFAULT",
    "clientId4": "DEFAULT",
    "demandNo1": "${demandNo}",
    "demandNo2": "${demandNo}",
    "demandNo3": "${demandNo}",
    "demandNo4": "${demandNo}"
  }
]

Now the first thing to do is to do is to group up the two common keys: clientId and demandNo; in jolt, you can use the * sign to generalize the key you want to take, for example:
{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "clientId*": "temp[&1].clientId",  //Here you are saying: Take every key that starts
                                           //with "client"
        "demandNo*": "temp[&1].demandNo"   //Same thing here
      }
    }
  }

Now the output is like this:
{
  "temp" : [ {
    "clientId" : [ "DEFAULT", "DEFAULT", "DEFAULT", "DEFAULT" ],
    "demandNo" : [ "${demandNo}", "${demandNo}", "${demandNo}", "${demandNo}" ]
  } ]
}

And finally we have to put everything in one array, by cicling the temp arrays and using their index to our advantage:
{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "temp": {
        "*": {
          "clientId": {
            "*": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[0].body.WLSPD001.WLSPDEXTREF001[&0].&1"
          },
          "demandNo": {
            "*": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[0].body.WLSPD001.WLSPDEXTREF001[&0].&1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

We used the [&0] to specify we are pointing to a specific index at very cicle.
The final jolt is this:
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "HEADER_SOURCE": "HOST",
        "HEADER_DESTINATION": "WAMAS",
        "HEADER_SEQUENCE": "0",
        "HEADER_CREATIONTIME": "${CreationTime}",
        "HEADER_RECORDTYPENAME": "WLSPD001",
        "clientId": "DEFAULT",
        "priority": "5",
        "typeId": "SHPG",
        "zone": "ZONE1",
        "sysPartnerLine": "1",
        "variant": "1",
        "clientId1": "DEFAULT",
        "clientId2": "DEFAULT",
        "clientId3": "DEFAULT",
        "clientId4": "DEFAULT",
        "demandNo1": "${demandNo}",
        "demandNo2": "${demandNo}",
        "demandNo3": "${demandNo}",
        "demandNo4": "${demandNo}"
      }
    }
},
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "HEADER_SOURCE": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].header.FULL.HEADER_SOURCE",
        "HEADER_DESTINATION": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].header.FULL.HEADER_DESTINATION",
        "HEADER_SEQUENCE": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].header.FULL.HEADER_SEQUENCE",
        "HEADER_CREATIONTIME": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].header.FULL.HEADER_CREATIONTIME",
        "HEADER_RECORDTYPENAME": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].header.FULL.HEADER_RECORDTYPENAME",
        "clientId": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.clientId",
        "data01": ["DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.demandNo", "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.WLSPDL001[&1].demandNo", "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.WLSPDL001[&1].hostWorkId"],
        "priority": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.priority",
        "zone": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.zone",
        "typeId": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.typeId",
        "TransactionType": {
          "WorkCreation": {
            "#CREATE": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&3].body.WLSPD001.operation"
          },
          "WorkCompletion": {
            "#COMPLETE": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&3].body.WLSPD001.operation"
          },
          "WorkCanceled": {
            "#CANCEL": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&3].body.WLSPD001.operation"
          }
        },
        "sysPartnerLine": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.WLSPDL001[&1].sysPartnerLine",
        "data02": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.WLSPDL001[&1].itemNo",
        "variant": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.WLSPDL001[&1].variant",
        "data04": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.WLSPDL001[&1].baseQty",
        "data03": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[&1].body.WLSPD001.WLSPDL001[&1].hostLuIds",
        "clientId*": "temp[&1].clientId",
        "demandNo*": "temp[&1].demandNo"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "temp": {
        "*": {
          "clientId": {
            "*": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[0].body.WLSPD001.WLSPDEXTREF001[&0].&1"
          },
          "demandNo": {
            "*": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[0].body.WLSPD001.WLSPDEXTREF001[&0].&1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


The only thing is that every clientId and demandNo will not have the number at the end (like clientId1 or demandNo3,...); if this thing is a problem, you can always add a &0 at the end of every line in the last shift(like this: "*": "DI_TELEGRAMS.DI_TELEGRAM[0].body.WLSPD001.WLSPDEXTREF001[&0].&1&0").
I suggest you to always reduce your jsons when working with jolt, this way it will be easier for you to understand the problem, and for others to help you solve it :)
